# LVM snapshot has virtual origin - can't merge

Tags: lvm

I'm unable to merge a lvm snapshot

```
# lvconvert --merge vg0/lv-malte
  Snapshot lv-malte has virtual origin.
```

This is what my volumes look like

```
# lvs -a
  LV                  VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin                      Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert0.00                                   
  lv-malte            vg0 swi-a-s---  12.00g      [lv-malte_vorigin]          63.58                                  
  [lv-malte_vorigin]  vg0 owi-aos--- 102.54g
  lvroot              vg0 -wi-ao---- 100.00g
  [...]
```

I'm stumped, what is a *virtual origin*? I didn't find the expression in the LVM man pages and google does not bring up anything useful either. How do I merge the snapshot and get rid of the virtual origin altogether?

Regards...volker